# How to activate new mode in Blender 2.8 that displays viewport objects with different colors?

Tags: color

I've been watching tutorial videos of the new Blender 2.8 and see it has something that that lets you display each object in your viewport with a different color to make it easier to distinguish them.  I'm trying to figure out how to activate this, but all my searches just turn up tutorials for assigning materials.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

*Viewport Shading* > *Color* > *Random*

[image]